# R - Removing tick mark without removing label

Tags: r, plot

I would like to remove the tick marks from a plot in R, but not the text associated with the individual tick marks. How do I do that?

My code is the following:

```
boxplot(boxDat ~ class, ylab = "Predictive Scoring", names = c("ANN", "Random\nForest", "Logistic\nRegression"), cex.axis=1, xaxt='n')
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
boxplot(count ~ spray, data = InsectSprays, col = "lightgray",xaxt = "n")
axis(side = 1,at = 1:6,letters[1:6],tick = FALSE)
```